# In RDBMs, what is the Replace actually mean in CRUD

Tags: crud

Every programmer knows what CRUD is, but what does Replace *actually* mean when it comes to RDBMs? With an object database, replace makes more sense, ie, you might have to replace an object with another object. But during runtime using an RDBMs, what are you replacing with what?

Or does CRUD actually stand for Create Read Update Delete? (makes more sense).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The later - create, read, update, delete

See: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Create,_read,_update_and_delete

Comment: but Read is also a bit dubious

Answer (score 0):

Create – If N doesn’t exist, then create it. If  already exists don’t do anything! So basically it won’t overwrite anything you already have, could be an issue if you decide to update the settings later.

Replace – Remove N if already exists, and create a new N with these settings. If N does not exist just create it with your settings. In short, whether N existed or not you’re getting it. If you have settings that you wish to keep and just want to add, then update is what you need to select. But could be an issue later knowing exactly what settings a user is actually getting as they might not match exactly the GPO.

Update – If N exists it will be updated with the new settings. If there are other settings associated with the drive mapping that aren’t specified here, they will be maintained. If N doesn’t exists create it. Nothing gets removed like with the Replace setting, but there is still a chance that you’ll overwrite something.

Delete – If that drive mapping exists, it will be removed. If N doesn’t exist it won’t do anything.

Personally i would almost always use replace. The setting i apply are the ones i want the user to have, i don’t want to be debugging a computer because i used update and legacy settings are being applied still.

Hope this help someone.

Source: http://wicher.co.uk/gpo-c-r-u-d-create-replace-update-delete/